# mootools:How to remove Drag?

Tags: javascript, mootools, drag

I make the 'el' element dragable with mootools:

```
new Drag(el, {x1:""});//the old drag binding
```

Now,I want to remove the old drag binding,and then create a new drag instead.

```
//update the el's drag binding
new Drag(el, {x2:""});//the new drag binding
```

But I have no proper idea to remove the old drag binding

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `detach` method.

Read more about how to use it at http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Drag#Drag:detach